# Generating GeoJson with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, geojson

I'm getting a lat/lon array with ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../m/m_share.php',
    data: 'zone=' + zone,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(tab) {
        var i = 0;
        var size = tab.length;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            var lat = tab[i]['lat'];
            var lon = tab[i]['lon'];
        }
    }
```

The "tab" param is a jscon_encode(array) sent by php of my lat/lon request from db.
What I would like to do is creating a geojson such as this one but with my lat/lon datas.

```
var geojson =
   {"name":"NewFeatureType",
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[{"type":"Feature",
                 "geometry":{"type":"LineString",
                             "coordinates":[[169.13693,-44.696476,296],[169.134602,-44.69764,295],[169.129983,-44.701164,299]]},
    "properties":null}]};
```

I tried to save the lat/lon in a var

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../m/m_share.php',
            data: 'zone=' + zone,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(tab) {
                var i = 0;
                var size = tab.length;
                for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                     var lat = tab[i]['lat'];
                     var lon = tab[i]['lon'];
                   if(i===size){
                      coord = coord+'['+lat+','+lon+']';
                       alert(coord);
                    }
                    else{
                      coord = coord+'['+lat+','+lon+']'+',';

                    }
                }
                }
            });
```

And then replace the lat/lon in the geoJson with my coord var but it seems that leaflet does not like it "Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, Nan)".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a bit vague. You want to create this `geojson` with PHP? How are you getting this data? Please edit and add a few more details.

Comment: Thanks you, I edited it should be better now

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a geojson object variable.

```
var geojson = {
    "name":"NewFeatureType",
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[{
        "type":"Feature",
        "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[]
        },
        "properties":null
    }]
};
```

then you do pushing into coordinates array

```
geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates.push([lat, lng]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, seems to be the right move but I cannot make it work since it keeps returning me this error Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined

Comment: @JChri `"features":[{` is an array and in the first index of that array there is an object. Therefore, it must be referenced like so, `geojson.features[0].geometry`. If its written like this: `"features":{` without the `[` then it should be referenced like this: `geojson.features.geometry`

Comment: @JChri Please show me in your OP what you did to get that error, or if you can please create a JSFIDDLE and we can get this resolved lickety split

Answer (score 6):

The approach mentioned by Pedro Estrada is correct. But there is a slight correction required.

GeoJson standard requires geographical points with (longitude,latitude) convention.

```js
var gj = {
    "name":"MyFeatureType",
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[]
};
```

Push a new feature object

```js
gj.features.push({ "type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "LineString","coordinates": []},"properties": null });
```

Add a coordinate to newly pushed object:

```js
lon=20;
lat=10;
gj.features[0].geometry.coordinates.push([lon,lat]);
```